# Python Lists of Lists Converting to Dict to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested-lists

Converting a massive list of lists into dictionary and code only works for the first item in the list of lists.

```
a_list = [[('Bedrooms', ' 4'),
  ('Street Address', ' 90 Lake '),
  ('Contact Phone', ' 970-xxx-xxxx'),
  ('Bathrooms', ' 5'),
  ('Price', ' $5,350,000'),
  ('Zip Code', ' 5000')],

  [('Bedrooms', ' 4'),
  ('Street Address', ' 1490 Creek '),
  ('Contact Phone', ' 970-xxx-xxx3'),
  ('Bathrooms', ' 10'),
  ('Price', ' $7,350,000'),
  ('Zip Code', ' 6000'),
  ('City', ' Edwards'),
  ('Price1', ' 4200000')],

[('Street Address', ' 280 Lane'),
  ('Bedrooms', ' 2'),
  ('Property Type', ' Townhouse'),
  ('Square Feet', ' 3000'),
  ('Bathrooms', ' 4'),
  ('Contact Phone', ' 303-xxx-xxxx'),
  ('MLS', ' 66666'),
  ('Contact Name', ' C Name'),
  ('Brokerage', ' Real Estate'),
  ('City', 'Creek'),
  ('Zip Code', '89899'),
  ('Price1', ' 2100000'),
  ('Posted On', ' Nov 13, 2019')
]]
```

Current code only assigns k,v to 1st item:

```
items = {}
for line in list:
    for i in range(len(line)):
        key = line[i][0]
        value = line[i][1]
        items[key] = value
        items.update(line)
```

RESULT:

```
items = {'Bedrooms':' 4'),
  ('Street Address': ' 90 Lake '),
  ('Contact Phone': ' 970-xxx-xxxx'),
  ('Bathrooms': ' 5'),
  ('Price': ' $5,350,000'),
  ('Zip Code': ' 5000'}
```

Ultimately, I want to build DataFrame matching keys and values from the list of lists.

Comment: Don't call your list list otherwise you will not be able use list() to create lists.

Comment: This is a one liner (calling your `list` variable `lists` instead): `df = pd.DataFrame(dict(item) for item in lists)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a nicer way to do this by using `map` to convert each list to a dict and then calling the `DataFrame` constructor on it. Also, do not use built-ins as variable names, in this case `list`. I went ahead and renamed your input data as the variable `data`.

```
dicts = list(map(dict, data))
pd.DataFrame(dicts)

  Bathrooms Bedrooms     Brokerage   ...    Square Feet Street Address Zip Code
0         5        4           NaN   ...            NaN       90 Lake      5000
1        10        4           NaN   ...            NaN    1490 Creek      6000
2         4        2   Real Estate   ...           3000       280 Lane    89899

[3 rows x 14 columns]
```

Comment: `list(map(dict, data))` --> `[dict(item) for item in data]` ?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile yes correct those are the exact same

Comment: Right, my point was that using a list comprehension probably makes more sense. It’s far more pythonic, especially since you’re calling `list()` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
unpacked = [{k: v for k,v in one_list} for one_list in list_of_lists]
pd.DataFrame(unpacked)
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary in python is a data structure that stores key-value pairs. Essentially there is a unique key that is needed and every time you add a key-value pair (using update) to the dictionary. It does the following:

1. Checks if key is present
2. If the key is present, it updates the value to the new value
3. If they key is not present, it adds the key-value pair to the dictionary

You could take a look at this link for better understanding of 'update'

https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/update.html

Although there are easier ways to do this, the issue with your code is the last line i.e

```
items.update(line)
```

Instead of your code, you could use the code below (if you choose to proceed down this same approach, rather than the approach suggested by other answers):

```
items = {}
new_list = [] # another list
for line in list:
    for i in range(len(line)):
        key = line[i][0]
        value = line[i][1]
        items[key] = value
    new_list.append(items) # use this line instead of your update
```

then

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(new_list)
```

This should give you the result that you are looking for.